# What is the Energy-Momentum Tensor? (its equation and for what all the elements in the equation stand for) and how to derive it?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

What is the [Energy-Momentum Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)? I know that this equation appears in Einstein's Field Equation.  I would like to know what the Energy Momentum Tensor stands for as an equation, like if $F = ma$ then the Energy momentum tensor equals_______________? (I would also like to know what each element of the equations stands for, like $F = ma$ where $m$ is mass and $a$ is acceleration).

A derivation of the Energy momentum tensor would be nice, if possible.

Comment: energy momentum tensor can be derived from the Lagrangian of the given problem considering the translational symmetry. Using the idea of Noether's currents to corresponding continuous symmetry(in this case Translational), the Noether's current is the Energy Momentum tensor.

Comment: What do Goldstein or Landau& Lifshitz say , did you read these texts?

Comment: no havent read them, but I sure will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relativity the energy-momentum tensor, also called [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor),
summarizes several densities.

The meaning of its components $T^{\mu\nu}$ is as follows,
with $m$ and $n$ being spatial indexes $(1,2,3)$
(see also [Stress-energy tensor - Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Components)):

- $T^{00}$ is energy density (energy per volume).
- $T^{m0}$ is energy flux density (energy per area and time).
- $T^{0n}$ is momentum density (momentum per volume).
- $T^{mn}$ is momentum flux density (momentum per area and time).

This tensor obeys a continuity equation
$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$$
which, when separated into time and space components,
just describes the conservation of energy and momentum.

In general relativity all these tensor components $T^{\mu\nu}$ can be
consistently defined as coming from a [Lagrangian density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory)#Einstein_gravity) $\mathcal{L}$
and its dependence on the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)) $g_{\mu\nu}$:
$$T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta(\sqrt{g}\mathcal{L})}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have a question though... the √g is what? and how can I isolate the energy momentum tensor from that equation? what is the meaning of δ? and what would happen if I wanted to find the covariant energy momentum tensor?

Comment: @ArmanBraca $g$ is the determinant of the $g_{\mu\nu}$ component matrix.

Comment: @ArmanBraca I have isolated $T^{\mu\nu}$ in the equation, and also corrected an error in it.

Comment: is the  δ a partial derivative? What is it? I greatly appreciate your help and the time you have taken to answer my questions.

Comment: @ArmanBraca The $\delta$ is a [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative).

Answer (score 0):

Start with a rank 2 describing mass in the rest frame for a single particle

$$
M^{ab} =  M\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
After Lorentz transform this is
$$
M^{ab} =  M\begin{pmatrix}
    v^0v^0 & v^0v^1 & v^0v^2 & v^0v^3\\
    v^1v^0 & v^1v^1 & v^1v^2 & v^1v^3 \\
    v^2v^0 & v^2v^1 & v^2v^2 & v^2v^3 \\
    v^3v^0 & v^3v^1 & v^3v^2 & v^3v^3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
If we now sum over all particles of matter within a region and replace mass with density, the resulting symmetrical tensor field is the stress-energy tensor, or energy-momentum
tensor, $T^{ab}$.

While the momentum vector, $p$, for a body, has a simple intuitive meaning as
the sum of the momenta of its component particles, it is less easy to see the
meaning of the sum of products, $v^{ab}$, in the stress-energy tensor. In statistics,
similar sums of products appear in the study of correlation. The stress-energy
tensor may be regarded as a measure of not just of total motion, but also of the
correlation (or lack of correlation) between the motions of component particles, described as “stress”. That is to say, it is a measure of the extent to which differences in particle velocities cannot be transformed away through a choice of reference frame.

The stress-energy tensor can also be understood by considering the sum of a
large number of terms (for individual particles) with the form of $M^{ab}$ in an
inertial reference frame. Its components can be compared to established expressions
for the densities of energy, momentum, pressure, and stress of matter in 3-space. Noting that at non-relativistic velocities $v^0\approx 1$, the stress-energy tensor has the form,

$$
  M\begin{pmatrix}
    E & p & p & p\\
    p & P & S & S \\
    p & S & P & S \\
    p & S & S & P \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $E$ is total energy, $p$ is 3-momentum, $P$ is pressure and $S$ is the $3\times 3$
stress tensor, which describes shear forces such as viscosity. The stress-energy
tensor thus describes the principle dynamical quantities of pre-relativistic physics
in a single structure.

It is also possible to give a treatment of the electromagnetic energy momentum tensor   for which energy is
$$T_{00}= \frac 1{8\pi} (E^2+B^2) $$
and momentum is given by
$$(T_{01},T_{02},T_{03}) = \frac 1{4\pi} (E\times B)$$